# Ember caching model

Tags: caching, ember.js, model

I've got an Ember application with two routes. Once in a while I need to do a model update on route 1.

If I switch between the two routes (1 -> 2 -> 1) I noticed that Ember reloads the previously loaded model (the one fetched at the first render of the route).

I am not using Ember Data, only a thin hand-made Ajax API.

Can I prevent model caching? If not, how can I update the store with the new model?

Thank you.

Comment: The [refresh](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh) method is probably what you need to call. Unfortunately, I can't really give you a good idea of _how_ or _when_ to call it. I'm actually surprised that Ember doesn't allow you to disable caching.

Comment: Thank you for the 'refresh' idea. I really find that Ember documentation could be a lot better. Hopefully it will be steadily improved.

Comment: How are you loading your model from the custom Ajax API for each route? Are you supplying a function for the `model` hook in `Ember.Route`?

Comment: The reason I ask is that you mention updating the store, but I think the data store (and its caching capabilities) are technically a part of EmberData. Are you integrating some part of EmberData with your custom Ajax API?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, i'm essentially supplying a function returning a promise as the routes' model. I am not working explicitly with any part of the ember data store.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `link-to` helper to switch between 1 -> 2 -> 1, the `model` hook never gets invoked. I believe the thinking is that if you are passing in the model (as the argument to `link-to`) then why should Ember waste another call to the server to fetch the model (again).

See the [following discussion](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/912) of the ways to remedy the issue including using `setupController` method which **does** get invoked.